# pysftp library not working in AWS lambda layer

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pysftp, aws-lambda-layers

I want to upload files to EC2 instance using **pysftp** library (Python script). So I have created small Python script which is using below line to connect

```
pysftp.Connection(
    host=Constants.MY_HOST_NAME,
    username=Constants.MY_EC2_INSTANCE_USERNAME,
    private_key="./mypemfilelocation.pem",
)
some code here .....
pysftp.put(file_to_be_upload, ec2_remote_file_path)
```

This script will upload files from my local Windows machine to EC2 instance using .pem file and it works correctly.

Now I want to do this action using **AWS lambda with API Gateway** functionality.

So I have uploaded Python script to AWS lambda. Now I am not sure how to use pysftp library in AWS lambda, so I found solution that add pysftp library Layer in AWS lambda Layer. I did it with

> pip3 install pysftp -t ./library_folder

And I make zip of above folder and added in AWS lambda Layer.

But still I got so many errors like one by one :-

> No module named 'pysftp'
>
> No module named 'paramiko'
>
> Undefined Symbol: PyInt_FromLong
>
> cannot import name '_bcrypt' from partially initialized module 'bcrypt' (most likely due to a circular import)
>
> cffi module not found

I just fade up of above errors I didn't find the proper solution. How can I can use pysftp library in my AWS lambda seamlessly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I build `pysftp` layer and tested it on my lambda with python 3.8. Just to see import and basic print:

```
import json
import pysftp

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    print(dir(pysftp))
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

I used the following docker tool to build the `pysftp` layer:

- https://github.com/lambci/docker-lambda

So what I did for `pysftp` was:

```
# create pysftp fresh python 3.8 environment
python -m venv pysftp

# activate it
source pysftp/bin/activate

cd pysftp

# install pysftp in the environemnt
pip3 install pysftp  

# generate requirements.txt
pip freeze > requirements.txt

# use docker to construct the layer
docker run --rm -v `pwd`:/var/task:z lambci/lambda:build-python3.8 python3.8 -m pip --isolated install -t ./mylayer -r requirements.txt

zip -r pysftp-layer.zip .
```

And the rest is uploading the zip into s3, creating new layer in AWS console, setting `Compatible runtime` to python 3.8 and using  it in my test lambda function.

You can also check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55696651/248823) how to use this docker tool (the docker command I used is based on what is in that link).

Hope this helps

Comment: also You want to make sure your .zip follows this folder structure when unzipped

python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/{LibrariesGoHere}.

Upload that zip, make sure the layer is added to the Lambda function and you should be good to go.

This is the structure that has worked for me. Thanks you so much for this help. You save my week.

Comment: I also have some questions like how to use .pem file in AWS lambda? and while uploading file to EC2 how to use temp location of AWS lambda?

Comment: `pem` is an important file. Can consider storing it as a secret string in Parameter Store, or in Lambda Environment variables (event encrypted with encryption helpers). Temp location is `/tmp` with max size of 500MB. Use it as you would on a normal instance. If have specific questions/issues maybe better to make new question.

Comment: I got an issue with the zip missing a hidden file see (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51219096/libffi-d78936b1-so-6-0-4-cannot-open-shared-object-file-error-on-aws-lambda-fun). And also place the contents of `mylayer` into a folder called `python` then rezip.

Comment: not working in MAC, I build the layer in EC2, then it is working, error was in "bcript"

Comment: @Bira Thanks for letting me know. If the answer was helpful, its upvote would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I still had some issues with the above accepted solution on Python 11 runtime, and changing the version of `cryptography` and the `brcrypt` packages based on [this reply](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/2108#issuecomment-1289297075) did the trick for me. After I installed `pysftp`, I ran these two:

```
pip install cryptography==3.4.8
pip install bcrypt==3.2.2
```