# Need to create an layer in AWS for the python library which has c++ language in it

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have zipped some external library like pymsql for python and created an layer in aws to use in the lambda function but some external library we cannot install it in our local and cannot be used in the layer because it have c++ language , so we need to don it in the linux environment and need to upload in the zip file. I need to know how to do it in the linux environment and use it in the layers

Comment: Why not launch linux EC2 instance and create layer there?

Comment: have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61337007/pysftp-library-not-working-in-aws-lambda-layer/61337716#61337716) as an example of using this docker [tool](https://github.com/lambci/docker-lambda) for making custom lambda layers.